# Ubisoft recently announced that soon gamers no longer "own" their games with the release of Ubisoft+. Does that make pirating them legal?

Tags: copyright, video-games

### Situation

---

Recently, according to IGN<sup>[[source]](https://t.co/zBYWyksuJI)</sup>, there was an announcement from the executive of Ubisoft that before video game subscriptions can really take off, gamers need to be comfortable with the idea of not physically owning their games. This is to refer to their subscription service that is going to launch soon, Ubisoft+.

This doesn't sit right with me, because we have Nintendo Switch Online and the PS and XBOX subscriptions, which are all extremely successful all while letting gamers actually "own" copies of their games.

So it just seems to me like Ubisoft is just trying to make everyone pay for a subscription just so they can play games by Ubisoft.

---

Say Ubisoft does make it so that gamers don't "own" their games. Would this technically make pirating their games legal?

Because even if you had gotten it legally, since it's digital, you technically don't have complete ownership of it because the access to digital media is able to be revoked at any time.

And if you pirate the software, sure, it's stealing of digital media, but technically you still don't have ownership of the pirated media because the software was never yours in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question misinterprets both Ubisoft's original statement and relevant law.

First, what Ubisoft execs [said](https://me.ign.com/en/ps5/217087/news/ubisoft-exec-says-gamers-need-to-get-comfortable-not-owning-their-games-for-subscriptions-to-take-of) is that *"subscription ... is still relatively small compared to the other models"*, which is why they're **not** switching to it entirely.
Some publishers have tried to go subscription-only, and it did not go well. This is especially impractical for Ubisoft, most of whose portfolio is traditional single-player games and 20 year old franchises.

Second, **you have never owned a computer game**, unless you happen to own a game studio. When you "buy" a game, legally you only purchase a license to play it, which can be perpetual or temporary.
Ubisoft is talking about the psychology of being able to collect games. They believe it to be a significant sales driver. Collecting subscription probably doesn't work as well.

This has no effect on the legal status and validity of the copyright and the license. In fact, a subscription-only service makes the status of piracy as illegal much clearer. The [first-sale doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-sale_doctrine) allows players to lend or sell physical copies to others, but there's no such right with subscriptions.

Comment: Ubisoft owns Prince of Persia, first released in **1989** - that's a 30 year old franchise.